# Background Notification OnClick With FCM Flutter app open up an empty activity

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed every step in the flutter documentation on how to implement firebase_messaging with the new flutter android embedding v2

I have no problem with receiving the notification in every app state (Foreground/Background/Terminated or Detached). Clicking on the notification works perfectly on other state except terminated.

**In terminated state**, when I try to click on the notification that is received while the app is detached, it opens up the application but **I do not receive any data in getInitialMessage** function which I should (according to the doc). Also, when I try to leave the app by pressing the back button, somehow the app **shows an extra empty activity underneath** it and I'm not sure why this happen. I want to get rid of it.

These problems only occurs if the notification received in terminated state.

The onBackgroundMessage listener works perfectly even in terminated state.

main.dart :

```
Future<void> _backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Message from background : " + message.notification.body);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //init notification service
  await NotificationService().initNotification();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundHandler);
```

home_page_screen.dart :
setupInteractedMessage() is called in initState()

```
Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    //Terminated State
    //Comes in from terminated app's notification
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) => {
          if (value != null)
            {print("ContentAvailable : " + value.contentAvailable.toString())}
        });

    //Foreground state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      String title = event.notification.title;
      String body = event.notification.body;
      int tag = int.parse(event.data["tag"]);
      //Dont show notification if inside conversation with the sender
      if (!Provider.of<ConversationBloc>(context, listen: false)
          .disableNotification(tag)) {
        NotificationService()
            .showNotification(tag, title, body, json.encode(event.data));
      } else {
        soundHandler.playOnNewMessageSound();
      }

      print("Received in foreground");
    });

    //Opened from background notification trigger and handler
    //It does not work if the app is detached only works in paused state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      NotificationService().selectNotification(json.encode(event.data));
      print("Received in background while the app is paused and not detached");
    });
  }
```

Video :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-De9Buv6ToLB13hIat7i9uZsQOSS2XJO/view?usp=drivesdk

My reference :
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Answer (score 4):

try adding this intent tag to your activity tag inside AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity>

....
 
<intent-filter> // <= add this
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

....
```

and don't forget to add field 'click_action' to your payload when sending FCM. eg : `'click_action' : 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'`.

Comment: I did try this before and nothing changed, according to the doc I dont have to change anything in the Manifest file anymore if using the latest firebase_messaging package. We only need to put the intent filter if we still use flutter android embedding v1

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `onMessageOpenedApp` state

```
A Stream event will be sent if the app has opened from a background state (not terminated).
If your app is opened via a notification whilst the app is terminated,
see [getInitialMessage].
```

So you have to go with `getInitialMessage` to try to add some delay,

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
    // handle app opened from notification
    RemoteMessage? remoteMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    // add your custom code here
});
```